# spark-streaming read from specific event hub partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

The azure event hub "my_event_hub" has a total of 5 partitions ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")

The readstream should only read events from partitions "0" and "4"

event hub configuration as streaming source:-

```
val name = "my_event_hub"
val connectionString = "my_event_hub_connection_string"
val max_events = 50


val positions = Map(
  new NameAndPartition(name, 0) -> EventPosition.fromEndOfStream,
  new NameAndPartition(name, 4) -> EventPosition.fromEndOfStream
)

val eventHubsConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
                    .setStartingPositions(start)
                    .setMaxEventsPerTrigger(max_Events)
```

official doc for structured-streaming-eventhubs-integation: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/structured-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md

Using the above configuration the streaming application reads from all 5 partitions of the event hub.
Can we read from specific partitions only?

For example read events only from 2 partitions "0" and "4" with the checkpoint and offsets pointed to the specific partitions.

Comment: There is one [open issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/458) had same question. Looks like the problem can't be solved

Comment: I don't have a test event-hub env can test here. And from doc `EventPosition` has a `enqueuedOn` [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/eventposition?view=azure-node-latest#properties). From example code `EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(Instant.now)` maybe this can be a Future time?

Comment: would it be an option to configure the starting and ending position per partition, and then select a value for the starting position in such a way that no  events are read from the partitions you want to exclude?